# showing transparent layout over a layout in Qt 4.8.4

Tags: qt, qt4

I Like to show a label that having a animated gif image over a listwidget.
listwidget is in a horizontal widget.  when i am trying to put that label on window it aligned horizontally to list widget. I want to show it over the Listwidget with transparent view.

```
QMovie *m= new QMovie("loadingImage.gif");
QLabel *l=new QLabel();
ui.mainlayout->add
l->setMovie(m);
m->start();
l->show();
```

Comment: do you mean by 'over' on top of or placed above list widget?

Comment: like dislabing the window and on top of window show the loading image that gives feel that something is loading

Answer (score 0):

Don’t add the transparent widget to the layout. Just set the window as the transparent widget’s parent then show the widget. You’re then responsible for positioning and resizing the transparent widget to cover the list widget.